# Ionic Uncaught ReferenceError Firebase is not defined on Android Logcat

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, reference

My project working ok on web. But I am getting reference error from Android device. This is an Ionic project and it is working on web good. But when I try to open it on my android device, it gives me Firebase error. Here is the logcat logs;

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(43)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (43)
```

Here is my index file;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lib/ionic-material/dist/ionic.material.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionicuirouter/ionicUIRouter.js"></script>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--Firebase Header-->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.1.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
var config = {
apiKey: "A",
authDomain: "w",
databaseURL: "h",
storageBucket: "w",
messagingSenderId: "5"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
...
```

So is there any error related with Android or am I missing something ? What is your advice about that? Thank you

//Answer

I have changed all my Firebase with latest relases. Also Cordova changed. Then problem solved. Thank you for answer.

Comment: why are you importing two different versions of `firebase`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a few issues with your code here.

1. You're loading two versions of `firebase.js`. That may cause conflict of the two versions

   2.The second `firebase` import is below `angularfire` which depends on `firebase` (i.e should be loaded before firebase) - HTML loads assets in order they are marked up.
2. You're loading your Javascript from a CDN, if your device has no internet for a brief time during initialization, you `Firebase` references will be undefined. Try downloading them and load from file.

Comment: a conflict would not explain a ReferenceError. Having same issue, only in android & cordova. Can't even test for a null or I get ReferenceError